# Check for IDs with rows from the same column

Tags: mysql

I would like to select all employee_ids that have been in cat = 3 and never been in cat = 2.

I think a self-join on the same table might work, but can't figure it out

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to just count the number of times each of these categories occurred:

```
select employee_id
from employees
group by employee_id
having count(case when cat = 3 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when cat = 2 then 1 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       e1.employee_id
       FROM employees e1
       WHERE e1.cat = 3
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM employees e2
                                    WHERE e2.employee_id = e1.employee_id
                                          AND e2.cat = 2);
```

Try indexes on `cat` and `employee_id` and `employee_id` and `cat` along with the above query:

```
CREATE INDEX employees_cat_employee_id
             ON employees
                (cat,
                 employee_id);

CREATE INDEX employees_employee_id_cat
             ON employees
                (employee_id,
                 cat);
```

The first one might be used for the outer `SELECT` alone, the second one support the inner `SELECT` but has `employee_id` first as it likely has better selectivity.